# Stay logged in while remote logging into drupal website from c# application

Tags: json, c#-4.0, drupal, logging, drupal-7

I'm trying my best to write an application which can communicate with a drupal website.
I have setup the Rest server and wrote an application to call login form.
the response is what i desired but I don't know how to store session and stay logged in.

I want to know how should I store the session coming from drupal website.
Its better to say I'm looking for a solution to stay logged in :)

any one can help?:(

Answer (score 0):

Drupal stores session details in 'session' table. You can check the table after the user has logged on all the pages s/he visits.

Comment: Drupal sends sessionID and sessionName for me but i don't know how should i have save them on my computer to stay logged in

Comment: Have a look at this manual: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php